# Browser needs reload for method to re work

Tags: javascript

This Meteor client code located in the client/lib.js returns true for the first time but if the method is called again it returns false. The two exact calls happens in the browser console.
Unless I hard reload the page, then it works again correctly the first time only.

Why and how to fix it? Thanks

```
validate = (function () {
  const patterns = {
    usernamePat: new RegExp('^[0-9a-zA-Z]{16}$', 'g')
  };
  return {
    username: (name) => {
      return patterns.usernamePat.test(some_username);
    }
  }
}());
```

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the correct parameter here: `patterns.usernamePat.test(some_username);`?

Comment: Yes, as a mater of fact, I just hit the up arrow in the browser console and it just recalls the last command that was typed.